# Can I change a parent component's State by passing the setState function to the Link Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple link set up to go to the details section of a particular item in a list.
However, when I pass the setter function in the Link component it errors out as all my other state variables are null.

The code looks like this:

```
<Link
to={"device" + "/" + comp.hostname}
state={{
time:time,
date:date,
currentJobs: currentJobs,
setCurrentJobs: setCurrentJobs
}}
```

My problem is that when I pass the `setCurrentJobs` variable, the link takes me to the next page, but says time is undefined.

I believe I have `useLocation` setup right inside the component the link references:

```
const location = useLocation()
const time = location.state.time
const date = location.state.date
const currentJobs = location.state.currentJobs
const setCurrentJobs = location.state.setCurrentJobs
```

The code works just fine if I don't pass along the setter function. Is it that the Link component doesn't allow a function to be passed?

Answer (score 0):

Putting a setter inside of another state is problematic. Consider this approach which simply uses React context in order to create a shareable `state` and `setState` that can be used between parent/child/sibling components.

Using React 18.2, Router 6:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

`index.js`

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import Provider from "./Provider";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

`Provider.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const defaultState = {
  App: "",
  SubComponentA: 0,
  SubComponentB: [],
};

export const defaultContextValue = {
  state: defaultState,
  setState: () => {},
};

export const AppContext = React.createContext(defaultContextValue);

export default function App({ children }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AppContext, defaultState } from "./Provider";
import ShowKeys from "./ShowKeys";
import SubComponentA from "./SubComponentA";
import SubComponentB from "./SubComponentB";

export default function App() {
  const { state, setState } = useContext(AppContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setState(defaultState);
  }, []);

  // add text to the shared 'App' state value
  const onChangeInput = (e) => setState((s) => ({ ...s, App: e.target.value }));

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
      <h1>Sibling / Child Component Context-Share</h1>

      <div
        style={{ border: "1px solid green", margin: "1rem", padding: "1rem" }}
      >
        <h3>App.js Context Values</h3>
        <ShowKeys />
        <input
          style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}
          value={state.App}
          onChange={onChangeInput}
        />
      </div>

      <SubComponentA />
      <SubComponentB />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`ShowKeys.js`

```
/**
 * Display context keys & values
 */
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./Provider";

export default function ShowKeys() {
  const { state } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
      }}
    >
      {Object.keys(state).map((key) => {
        const value = state[key];

        return (
          <span>
            {key} = {key === "SubComponentB" ? JSON.stringify(value) : value}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`SubComponentA.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./Provider";
import ShowKeys from "./ShowKeys";

const SubComponentA = () => {
  const { state, setState } = useContext(AppContext);

  // increment the shared 'SubComponentA' state value
  const onModifyState = () =>
    setState((s) => ({ ...s, SubComponentA: s.SubComponentA + 420 }));

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", margin: "1rem", padding: "1rem" }}>
      <h2>Sub Component A</h2>
      <ShowKeys />
      <button style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }} onClick={onModifyState}>
        Modify state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubComponentA;
```

`SubComponentB.js`

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./Provider";
import ShowKeys from "./ShowKeys";

const SubComponentB = () => {
  const { setState } = useContext(AppContext);

  // append a new random integer to the 'SubComponentB' state array value
  const onModifyState = () =>
    setState((s) => ({
      ...s,
      SubComponentB: [
        ...s.SubComponentB,
        {
          id: s.SubComponentB.length + 1,
        },
      ],
    }));

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", margin: "1rem", padding: "1rem" }}>
      <h2>Sub Component B</h2>
      <ShowKeys />
      <button style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }} onClick={onModifyState}>
        Modify state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SubComponentB;
```

Try out a [working Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-2-router-6-shared-state-context-uurj21) I just created to better understand shareable state. It helps avoid prop-drilling and is a clean solution for sharing state between components.

Here's the end result after interacting with all 3 components - all 3 components know about each other's states.

[image]